# What does &variableName do when it's a parameter of a function?

Tags: c, pointers

Ok so I've been given some "simple" C code that calls a function, and need to build said function that will convert the temperature from F to C and then C to F.  However I'm not exactly sure how to handle all the different variables that are being passed to the function.

here is the existing code:

```
int main() 
{
  int degrees1 = 50, degrees2;
  char scale1 = 'F', scale2;
  convert_weight(degrees1, scale1, &degrees2, &scale2);
  printf("%d %c = %d %c\n");
  degrees1 = 10;
  scale1 = 'C';
  convert_weight(degrees1, scale1, &degrees2, &scale2);
  printf("%d %c = %d %c\n");
  return 0;
}
```

I don't understand what all the variables mean in the function call.

I would know what to do, if I didn't have to pass all the different things to the function, but probably can't mess with main.

How do I write a function that accepts parameters of that form?

Comment: So, to clarify, is the part you're having the most trouble with the `&degrees2, &scale2` part?

Comment: This question is too broad - it boils down to "How do function calls in C work?" StackOverflow handles more specific questions. I highly recommend you go over what materials you have and/or look at some introductory C tutorials.

Comment: @SamIam Yes, because I don't know what to do with them in my function.  I've tried ignoring them but then when I compile I get notified that ""warning: more '%' conversions than data arguments [-Wformat]
  printf("%d %c = %d %c\n");"" and I think it has to do with the pointers?

Comment: @MattKline  I read the question, and even thought the OP doesn't say it outright, it looks like he does have a specific question, except he just hasn't made it seem that way from the title.  It looks like he needs to understand the `&variablename` syntax in c

Comment: Well ok, I've been looking at tutorials for the past few hours, and none seem to help, neither do the notes, but point taken, I'll keep trying to figure it out myself.  Thanks.

Comment: @DanielLoveJr this is a perfectly acceptable question.  You just kinda sabotaged yourself with your title of `Need help understanding everything this C code is doing`.  When your title indicates that you `need help with everything`, then people are already primed to believe that this is a bad question before they even begin to read it.

Comment: Well now that I think about it it's not a very well phrased question anyways.  I don't usually come here unless I'm already a bit frustrated so I just quickly hammered something out that kinda made sense to me.  I'm sure there are plenty of kids who come around looking for free answers to homework questions.  I don't want that, I just want to understand what the professor is looking for with that main statement, so I can write my little function.  The pointers are confusing to me and not really explained in depth in our lecture notes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you have to write a function with this prototype:

```
void convert_weight(int degrees1, char scale1, int *degrees2, char *scale2);
```

Then, in the function body, you can use `*degrees2` as an input/output `int` value, and `*scale2` an input/output `char`.

In your simple code you do not need further mess with the pointers.

PS: When you say:

```
printf("%d %c = %d %c\n");
```

you probably want:

```
printf("%d %c = %d %c\n", degrees1, scale1, degrees2, scale2);
```

or else it will render undefined behaviour.

Comment: Ah ok, that's why my print stuff wasn't working at all, okies, thanks a bunch this is the kind of direction I needed, sorry my post was obtuse I'm just not sure how to phrase things sometimes.